# Calling ajax function in succes section of other ajax function?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Could someone explain how to refresh some sections in html code with ajax after success of another ajax function? This is a problem: after first ajax function I put some data in database, and then I want to refresh data on page.

Comment: As you mentioned in the title, just call the the second Ajax function in the success handler of the first Ajax function. What specific problem do you have doing that?

Comment: You could do both in the same call, or...what have you tried?  Why can't you just put another ajax call in the success function>

Comment: the question itself seems to be self answering...where's the code that isn't working?

Comment: Sounds like you should use your success function (or whatever callback from the server you have available) and update the DOM according to the data you receive. It would be better if you posted a code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic could be like this:

```
(1) Save data
(2) Put a delay
(3) Then call another ajax function to get data that was justed updated
(4) Then update html elements.
```

Following are code sample:

```
function SaveAndRefresh() {
//do something
showSpinningCircle(); // if you like
//collection data
var data = collect your data;
$.ajax({
    url: saveActionUrl,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {
        if (!data.error) {
            //(2) put some delay to make sure data updating is done
            setTimeout(function () {
                //(3)
                RefreshHtml(data);
            }, 2000);
        } else {
           //show error message;
        }
    }
 });
}
function RefreshHtml(data)
{ 
   //(4)
   $('#elementid').html( data formatted );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the success handler of the first ajax function.  Using jquery it would look a bit like this:

```
$.post('/url-to-process',$('#form').serialize(),function(data) {
    // do something with data
    $('#dom_object_you_want_to_update').html(data);
});
```

see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 0):

Use knockout. Goes nice hand-in-hand with jquery and ajax.

As for your question
inside the success of first call if you had the new data returned from the call skip to next step, else make a call to get the data from db.

assuming data is in some container element,

var myContainer = document.getElementById("...");
myContainer.html('{returned data}');

sorry for poor scripting, but that's the idea.